# Match two dataframes by dates between two datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**DATA**

df1 has project name, manager name, and the start and end date for each project. Start date may have missing values, but supp_date is always available as an approximation.

```
project  manager    start_date    end_date      supp_date
Apple    A          2001-05-03    2002-08-09    2002-05-10
Apple    B          2002-10-03    2003-11-12    2002-10-09
Orange   D          nan           2002-10-21    2002-06-25
Banana   C          nan           2003-01-02    2002-11-03
Banana   D          nan           2003-12-15    2003-02-12
Peach    C          2003-07-21    2003-10-12    2003-07-23
```

df2 only has date and project name:

```
project    begin_date
Apple      2002-01-02
Banana     2003-05-13
```

**IDEA**

For each project in df2, I want to find out its manager. Since the same project has different manager in different periods, I can use the date. For example, project Apple in df2 started on 2002-01-02. There are two projects with name Apple in df1, but 2002-01-02 is in between 2001-05-03 and 2002-08-09. So we know the manager should be A for Apple in df2.

Project Banana in df2 started on 2003-05-13. Since there is no start_date for Banana projects in df1, we use supp_date as start_date. So 2003-05-13 is in between 2003-02-12 and 2003-12-15, and we know the manager is D.

**RESULT**

```
project    begin_date    manager
Apple      2002-01-02    A
Banana     2003-05-13    D
```

Is there any fast way to do the following? df2 is really large (~1 million rows), so I think a loop would be very slow...

1) for each project in df2, check which project in df1 has the same name

2) based on 1), if start_date is non-missing, use start_date. Otherwise, use supp_date

3) find manager if begin_date is in between start_date and end_date, or between supp_date and end_date if start_date is missing.

Thank you very much for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `merge` and `between` (assuming that df2 will not have duplicate projects with a different begin_date):

```
# merge on project
merge = df.merge(df2, on='project')

# fill missing start_date with supp_date
merge['start_date'] = merge['start_date'].fillna(merge['supp_date'])

# boolean indexing with between
merge[merge['begin_date'].between(merge['start_date'], merge['end_date'])]

  project manager start_date   end_date  supp_date begin_date
0   Apple       A 2001-05-03 2002-08-09 2002-05-10 2002-01-02
3  Banana       D 2003-02-12 2003-12-15 2003-02-12 2003-05-13
```

You can then drop your unwanted columns.

Comment: This is brilliant!! Thanks a lot for getting me started. Unfortunately, df2 have many duplicate project names... but it looks like this should still work...?